# Indexing irregular String Data with special characters(;+) into Solr using Apache Nifi

Tags: solr, full-text-search, apache-nifi, dataimporthandler

Im new to Apache Nifi, im try to implement it as a replacement for Solr Native Data Import Handler(DIH) which is now deprecated in Solr vr.9.
Concrete here is the problem: I can import all other fields from Oracle database except data in this field that gives the following error:Error adding field 'FIELD_NAME'='77777383;+4377777383' msg=For input string: "77777383;
I suspect the problem lies with the special characters ";+" included in the string

The nifi-app log looks like this:

> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at https://servername:9999/solr/core: ERROR: [doc=4241b407-c29b-40c2-ad46-2dae92fb3694] Error adding field 'FIELD_NAME'='77777383;+4377777383' msg=For input string: "77777383;+4940866485409"
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:681)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
> at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:231)
> at org.apache.nifi.processors.solr.PutSolrRecord.index(PutSolrRecord.java:325)
> at org.apache.nifi.processors.solr.PutSolrRecord.doOnTrigger(PutSolrRecord.java:251)
> at org.apache.nifi.processors.solr.SolrProcessor.onTrigger(SolrProcessor.java:132)
> at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
> at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1360)
> at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
> at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.AbstractTimeBasedSchedulingAgent.lambda$doScheduleOnce$0(AbstractTimeBasedSchedulingAgent.java:59)
> at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here is the solr definition of the field in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="tele_1" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" maxTokenLength="255"/>
<filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" maxPosAsterisk="3" withOriginal="true" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" maxTokenLength="255"/>
<filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" maxPosAsterisk="3" withOriginal="true" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

### And Solr.log:

> 2023-09-08 05:52:48.348 ERROR (qtp1345265484-63) [ x:vdb]
> o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> ERROR: [doc=2d74b84a-33c2-488e-8331-eee4a2c6120e] Error adding field
> 'FAX_OLZ'=''77777383;+4377777383'' msg=For input string:
> "'77777383;+4377777383'" => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> ERROR: [doc=2d74b84a-33c2-488e-8331-eee4a2c6120e] Error adding field
> 'FAX_OLZ'='7313 2592;+49 431 71745 2592' msg=For input string:
> "'77777383;+4377777383'"  at
> org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:258)
> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR:
> [doc=2d74b84a-33c2-488e-8331-eee4a2c6120e] Error adding field
> 'FAX_OLZ'='77777383;+4377777383' msg=For input string:
> "'77777383;+4377777383'"  at
> org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:258)
> ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
> magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
> org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:100)
> ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
> magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
> org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.lambda$makeLuceneDocs$0(AddUpdateCommand.java:233)
> ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
> magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:?]    at
> org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232)
> ~[lucene-core-9.3.0.jar:9.3.0 d25cebcef7a80369f4dfb9285ca7360a810b75dc
>
> - ivera - 2022-07-25 12:30:23]    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:432)
>   ~[lucene-core-9.3.0.jar:9.3.0 d25cebcef7a80369f4dfb9285ca7360a810b75dc
> - ivera - 2022-07-25 12:30:23]    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1532)
>   ~[lucene-core-9.3.0.jar:9.3.0 d25cebcef7a80369f4dfb9285ca7360a810b75dc
> - ivera - 2022-07-25 12:30:23]    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1521)
>   ~[lucene-core-9.3.0.jar:9.3.0 d25cebcef7a80369f4dfb9285ca7360a810b75dc
> - ivera - 2022-07-25 12:30:23]    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:1048)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:416)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:369)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:300)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessorFactory$RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:76)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.NestedUpdateProcessorFactory$NestedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(NestedUpdateProcessorFactory.java:78)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:269)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:544)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:356)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:51)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:353)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:235)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:111)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:535)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:71)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:111)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:82)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:123)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:342)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:286)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:338)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:236)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:303)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:193)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:126)
>   ~[solr-solrj-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944
> - magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]     at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:135)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:74)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:101)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:84)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:224)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2865)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:887)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:606)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:250)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:218)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:257)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:227)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
>   ~[jetty-security-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
>   ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
>   ~[jetty-rewrite-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:772)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
>   ~[jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
>   ~[jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
>   ~[jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:9.4.48.v20220622]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "'77777383;+4377777383'"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]  at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]   at
>   org.apache.solr.schema.LongPointField.createField(LongPointField.java:161)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.schema.PointField.createFields(PointField.java:270)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:67)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addOriginalField(DocumentBuilder.java:302)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:218)
>   ~[solr-core-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1 d998e63978abfedde3b75bab4ba6e1e78ddb5944 -
>   magibney - 2023-01-17 19:58:00]   ... 111 more 2023-09-08 05:52:53.653
>   INFO  (searcherExecutor-12-thread-1-processing-vdb) [ x:vdb]
>   o.a.s.c.QuerySenderListener QuerySenderListener done. 2023-09-08
>   05:52:53.684 INFO  (searcherExecutor-12-thread-1-processing-vdb) [
>   x:vdb] o.a.s.c.SolrCore Registered new searcher autowarm time: 22 ms

Does anyone have an idea how I can index this field into solar with NIfi without changing its contents and still have it searchable in Query. I have tried WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory and  PatternTokenizer without any success.

Comment: Do you have any entries in Solr's own log?

Comment: Hallo @MatsLindh am attaching the log for solr.log on the main Question thread

Comment: The error message indicates that the field is actually defined as a numeric field and not as a text field - do you have the relevant part of the schema? Was the field defined as a numeric field the first time you started indexing content into the field? Have you tried clearing out the index completely and reindexing?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your reply. Here are the things I have tried: Deleted the index completely(deleted solr data folder) tried definining the field diffrently in schema.xml as"solr.TextField" seems does not help. I dont know where else I may have defined it as Numeric, or Solr the data format from Nifi and simply interprates it as Numeric? i dont know where else to check

Comment: Add your actual schema for that given field to the question, including the field type, (also make sure whether it is a dynamic field definition that matches the name of the field) and that you're actually using the schema and not the schemaless mode (where it will guess the field type based on the first value submitted for the field)

Comment: @MatsLindh That could be the problem, I gues am using schemaless mode- ''managed schema'' where solr guesses the field type and modifies the file managed-schema- accordingly. How do I tell solr to ignore this behaviour and define only this field as a string?

Comment: Define the schema first, then import - or disable the schemaless mode entirely. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/schemaless-mode.html#configuring-schemaless-mode and the `mutable` setting.

Comment: Resolved. I had problem with Schema.xml file. Solr was not reading this file correctly to load "managed schema"